# Website layout not positioning right

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a template for my website from scratch and everything was going good until I wanted to make a news bar underneath my navbar and welcome message bar. For some reason the spot that would be for news goes above the navbar and I can't figure out why!

[image: Screen shot]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #0e0e0f;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#navbar {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
#navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
#navbar ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
#navbar ul li a:visited:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: yellow;
}
#top-container {
  margin: 0;
  background: black: ;
  background: linear-gradient(black, grey);
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
#welcome-message {
  margin: 250px 150px 100px 300px;
  color: white;
}
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background: #1f1f21;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 700px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Placeholder</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top-container">
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home" class="active">Place Holder</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 id="welcome-message">Welcome to<br>
  Place holder!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <h1>News Placeholder</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `position:absolute` from `#top-container` and `margin-top: 700px;` from `.main-content`.

You have bug in `background: black:;` inside `#top-container`. Remove `:` to fix it.

Your code is not pretty but this solved your problem. Here is live example:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 background: #0e0e0f;
 font-family: Impact;
 font-size: 22px;
}
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
#navbar{
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

#navbar ul li{
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
}


#navbar ul li{
    margin: 10px;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover{
 color: yellow;
}
#navbar ul li a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
#navbar ul li a:visited:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: yellow;
}

#top-container{
 margin: 0;
 background: black;
 background: linear-gradient(black, grey);
 width: 100%;
 height: 650px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

#welcome-message{
 margin: 250px 150px 100px 300px;
 color: white;
}

.main-content{
 width: 100%;
 height: 650px;
 background: #1f1f21;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Placeholder</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="top-container">
 <nav id="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#Home" class="active">Place Holder</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Place Holder</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
  <h1 id="welcome-message">Welcome to<br>
  Place holder!</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="main-content">
  <h1>News Placeholder</h1>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

To remove bar of space between both content areas remove margin from `h1`. Check updated code.

Comment: Thank you! I know my code isn't pretty I started learning a few days ago. Any tips you have would be much appreciated! Also how do I remove that bar of space that is created now in between both my content areas? I want them to touch with no space in between.